# Code splitting with entry dependency but get an error and my webpack version is 4.41.6(the lastest by now)

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

**project**

```sh
../code_splitting_with_entry/
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── another-module.js
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

**./src/index.js**

```js
import _ from 'loadsh';

function component() {
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    // Loadsh 现在通过import导入
    element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

    return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**another-module.js**

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

console.log(
  _.join(['Another', 'module', 'loaded!'], ' ')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: { import: './src/index.js',dependOn: 'shared'},
        another: { import: './src/another-module.js',dependOn: 'shared' },
        shared: 'loadsh'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

but this will yield the following build result:

```sh
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['index'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

It somes like tell me the entry points only support `string` | `[string]`？But the [link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dependencies) tell me the object (`object = { import string | [string], dependOn string | [string], filename string }`) is also ok.

Any body can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you stick by this problem when following the webpack guide. Check you guide's version carefully. Webpack's main documents (there's no version in the URL) are for V5, but giving a confusing tag 'v4.41.6'. There should be a note at the bottom of navigation column:

> You are reading webpack 5 documentation. Change here to:

and there is a link to v4 documents.

看来象是跟 webpack 指南的时候被困了吧。注意看下指南的版本。Webpack 的主文档（URL中没有版本）已经是第5版的，但它很坑的加了个 v4.41.6 的标记。导航栏底下会有一句话告诉你是第5版，还有到第4版的链接。

Answer (score 0):

I found that i used 'loadsh' in index.js, but 'lodash' in another-module.js.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was I was reading v5 (beta) you should be aware what version you are reading.

For version 4 the object is not a valid option to pass on entry:

```js
//change
entry: {
        index: { import: './src/index.js',dependOn: 'shared'},
        another: { import: './src/another-module.js',dependOn: 'shared' },
        shared: 'loadsh'
    },

// to 

entry: {
  index: './src/index.js',
  another: './src/another-module.js',
},
```

in case you are using webpack 4 use this guide
https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/